# Hangfire runs at wrong time

Tags: hangfire

I'm using Hangfire to run a recurring job at 7 am from Monday to Friday.
Today at around 7.30 am, I went to hangfire dashboard and saw that the job was just running 1 minute ago and it was still processing.

I don't know why the job runs at the wrong time (around 30 mins delay). 
Is there anyone here can explain? Thank you.

My cron for the job is "0 7 * * 1-5".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the hangfire schema tables job creation times? Also check if the DB server timing is different than from your task server.
If above options seems alright then try, adding a Timezone parameter to your jobs, AddOrUpdate() method call.

Example,

```
_recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
                configuration.Name,
                Hangfire.Common.Job.FromExpression<T>(p => p.Execute(configuration.Name, JobCancellationToken.Null)),
                configuration.Frequency,
                TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```